# QSortFilterProxyModel - find out id index of source model is in proxy model

Tags: c++, qt, model, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have QSortFilterProxyModel and QModelIndex of item in the model that is set as source to QSortFilterProxyModel. I need to know is this QModelIndex included in the SortFilterProxyModel model with current filtering settings or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QSortFilterProxyModel * fm;
QModelIndex      sourceIndex;

if (fm->mapFromSource(sourceIndex).isValid()) {
 // element in filter proxy
} else {
 // element is not in filter proxy
}
```

Comment: I received index from view, it was already indexes of QSortFilterProxyModel, so I just needed to check model() method from index. And for question that I wrote your answer is right answer =)